# Cordova with tesseract

Tags: cordova, tesseract, tesseract.js

Can anyone please provide a link or sample to make a mobile app using the cordova and tesseract.
I can't use the phonegap or ionic, its a client requirement
for last two days m trying to make it, but nothing worked